# Optimize metrics for Fraud Detection Imbalanced Data

Tags: machine-learning, classification, resampling, imbalanced-data, fraud-prevention

I would need your help to improve my model performance. As mostly happens for fraud detection, I have an imbalanced dataset (0.1/0.9). I would like to optimize the recall for my target 1 and 0, because in one case I want to avoid fraud detection, on the other hand I want to limit the cost of targeting non-fraudulent clients as fraudulent because the 5% of the incorrect classified would decrease my revenue by €3K each (while targeting correct fraudulent would make me save 1k of loss for each customer detected).

First question I have is: what metrics would you consider based on this problem? I am more focused on recall, but I would read your opinions.

Second question: How can I improve my model performance?

So far, the best results I got without lowering the treshold is:

Accuracy: 0.89
Confusion Matrix:
[[3153  279]
[ 145  297]]

Classification Report:
precision    recall  f1-score   support

```
       0       0.96      0.92      0.94      3432
       1       0.52      0.67      0.58       442

accuracy                           0.89      3874
```

while if I lower the treshold to increase the recall of target 1:

Accuracy: 0.61
Confusion Matrix:
[[1959 1473]
[  42  400]]

Classification Report:
precision    recall  f1-score   support

```
       0       0.98      0.57      0.72      3432
       1       0.21      0.90      0.35       442

accuracy                           0.61      3874
```

I tried several models:
Linear Regression, XGBoost, Random forest and SVM

Moreover, even over/undesampling techniques (only on the train set)
RandomOverSampling, RandomUnderSampling, SMOTE

Do you have any other advice?

Comment: Can you add more details? Provide us an example of observation

Answer (score 0):

`LogisticRegression` would be more suited to this classification problem than `LinearRegression`, so it's worth a try if you haven't already.

The ROC metric summarises both recall and false positives. An ideal ROC metric of 1.0 would correspond to a scenario where you achieve both perfect recall and no false positives. `sklearn` has some weighted variants of the [ROC metric](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html). This provides a way of *scoring* a model after it has been trained.

Note that you can't use this type of metric to directly *optimise* the model in `sklearn` - you'd need to switch to PyTorch or similar and use a custom loss function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I read many threads online where people discuss whether AUC is appropriate metric for imbalanced dataset or not.

Using ROC-AUC I have 0.88 and I am able to set a threshold to get a recall of 0.8 for both target 0 and 1. The results seem quite decent to me, but the f1-score for target 1 is still around 0.4/0.45.

Do you think that in this case, where I want to predict as many true positive as I can, and at the same time reduce the number of false positive, which metric should I consider?

Comment: Perhaps you could make a custom metric that weights recall and FPR according to how much importance you want to give to each? Also, I think it could be worth posting your question on CrossValidated (or DataScience). You might get more nuanced input on different metrics and their suitability for your use case.